# PowerShell to backup a Web application

Tags: powershell, backup, restore

I need a PowerShell script which could perform the following:

- How to Back up and Content Database of a Web Application
- Restore a Content Database on a newly created Web Application

Comment: and what is your question ?

Comment: I need a PowerShell script which could handle both of above things :)

Comment: this is still not a question. Anyways, Why don't you simply detach DB from the source app, then reattach the DB to the target APP (backup the ocntent database in SQL server first)

Comment: Because Steve B's comment bears repeating: http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3pvcw2/

Comment: Don't be afraid to bing or browse TechNet for the standard powershell commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both web apps are in the same farm, the fastest and easiest way is to detach DB from app A and reattach DB from B.

```
$srcApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://app1
$targetApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://app2

$dbs = Get-SPContentDatabase -WebApplication $srcApp  | % { $_.Name }

Get-SPContentDataBase -WebApplication $srcApp | Dismount-SPContentDataBase

Remove-SPWebApplication

$dbs | % { Mount-SPContentData -Name $_ -WebApplication $targetApp }
```

This script should do the job (can't test by now, don't fire it blindly).

**[Edit] and of course, backup the whole content database before**

Answer (score 3):

Using the SharePoint PowerShell console

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory <BackupFolder> -BackupMethod {Full | Differential} -Item <WebApplicationName> [-Verbose]
```

See this MSDN article: [Use Windows PowerShell to back up a Web application in SharePoint Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748650.aspx#Powershell).

Use this command to restore a content DB:

```
Restore-SPFarm -Directory <Backup folder name> -RestoreMethod Overwrite -Item <Content database name> [-BackupId <GUID>] [-Verbose]
```

See this TechNet article: [Use Windows PowerShell to restore a SharePoint content database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748604.aspx#section1).

Please ensure that you understand these commands and run tests to know what is going to happen. Other links:

[Restore-SPFarm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607783.aspx)

[Backup-SPFarm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607881)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890117